# Beamer set slidewidth

Tags: beamer, page-breaking, presentations, textwidth

What is the command that sets the width of the slide? because in some templates my images go to the next line and in some they don't and I don't know whats the code that arranges for the horizontal space.

[image]

```
\newif\ifhandout
\input{mytalk11}
\usepackage{minipage-marginpar} %\newcommand{\C}{\ensuremath{\mathcal{C}}} \newcommand{\ECT}{\ensuremath{\textsc{ECT}}} %\newcommand{\0}{\mathbb{0}} \usepackage{dsfont}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[square] % change to default circle later

\usepackage[algosection,ruled,lined,linesnumbered,longend]{algorithm2e} \usepackage{algorithmic} \usepackage[english]{babel} \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\begin{document}



\begin{frame}{}
     \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{PreTiling.png}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{PreTiling.png}



    \end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Image is attached. Here is the template called `mytalk11.tex`:

```
%\handouttrue

\ifhandout
\documentclass[mathserif,11pt,handout]{beamer}
\else
\documentclass[onlymath,11pt]{beamer}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\fi


\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb,graphicx}
\usepackage{mathbbol}

\usetheme{boxes}

%colour definition
\definecolor{mylightblue}{RGB}{204, 230, 230} %Remark 
\definecolor{mydarkblue}{RGB}{0, 77, 77} %Remark Title

\definecolor{mylightpink}{RGB}{255, 217, 217} %Exercise
\definecolor{mydarkpink}{RGB}{166, 0, 0} %Exercise Title

\definecolor{mylightyellow}{RGB}{255, 255, 166}%Definition
\definecolor{mydarkbrown}{RGB}{125, 77, 0}%Definition Title

\definecolor{mylightpurple}{RGB}{217, 217, 255}%Theorem
\definecolor{mydarkpurple}{RGB}{0, 0, 128}%Theorem Title

\definecolor{mylightgreen}{RGB}{217, 255, 217}%Example
\definecolor{mydarkgreen}{RGB}{0, 128, 0} %Example Title

\definecolor{mygraydark}{RGB}{160,160,160}
\definecolor{mygraylight}{RGB}{240,240,240}

\definecolor{mybluedark}{HTML}{002239}
\definecolor{mybluelight}{HTML}{4FA2D7}
\definecolor{myyellow}{HTML}{BC9830}
\definecolor{myred}{HTML}{BE3100}
\definecolor{myblue}{HTML}{044B7A}
\definecolor{myalertred}{HTML}{BE3100} %alert colour
\definecolor{approvedgreen}{RGB}{0,85,0} % #006E00

%title bar grey
%change structure colors
\setbeamercolor{blue text}{fg=myblue}
\setbeamercolor{green text}{fg=mydarkgreen}
\setbeamercolor{red text}{fg=myred}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=mygraydark}
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=myred}
\setbeamercolor{palette primary}{fg=black,bg=mybluedark}
\setbeamercolor{palette secondary}{fg=mybluedark,bg=mybluelight}
\setbeamercolor{palette tertiary}{fg=white,bg=mybluedark}
%\setbeamercolor{palette quaternary}{fg=black,bg=white}

%Add footline
\addfootbox{palette secondary}{\hfill\insertshorttitle\quad}
\addfootbox{palette tertiary}{\quad
  \insertsection 
  \ifx\insertsubsection\empty  \else  ~-- \insertsubsection \fi
}

%Titles
\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=palette secondary}
\setbeamerfont{title}{series=\bfseries}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{series=\bfseries}
\setbeamerfont{block title}{series=\bfseries}

\newcommand{\heading}[2]{\textcolor{mygraydark}{\textbf{#1}} \vspace{0.7em}}

%remove navigation symbols
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

%itemized and enumerated lists
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[triangle]
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[square]
\setbeamercolor{item}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{enumerate item}{fg=black}

%create green box for examples
\setbeamercolor*{block title example}{fg=mydarkgreen,
bg= mylightgreen}
\setbeamercolor*{block body example}{fg= black,
bg= mylightgreen}


%remark block
\newenvironment<>{remark}
{\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=mydarkblue,bg=mylightblue}%
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=mylightblue}%
\begin{block}{Remark} #1}
{\end{block}}

%remarks block
\newenvironment<>{remarks}
{\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=mydarkblue,bg=mylightblue}%
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=mylightblue}%
\begin{block}{Remarks} #1}
{\end{block}}

%Exercise block
\newenvironment<>{exercise}
{\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=mydarkpink, bg=mylightpink}%
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=mylightpink}%
\begin{block}{Exercise} #1}
{\end{block}}

%Definition block
\newenvironment<>{defn}
{\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=mydarkbrown, bg=mylightyellow}%
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=mylightyellow}%
\begin{block}{Definition} #1}
{\end{block}}

%Theorem block
\newenvironment<>{theorem}
{\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=mydarkpurple, bg=mylightpurple}%
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=mylightpurple}%
\begin{block}{Theorem} #1}
{\end{block}}

\newenvironment<>{lemma}
{\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=mydarkpurple, bg=mylightpurple}%
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=mylightpurple}%
\begin{block}{Lemma} #1}
{\end{block}}

\newenvironment<>{lem}[2]
{\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=mydarkpink, bg=mylightpink}%
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=mylightpink}%
\begin{block}{#1} #2}
{\end{block}}

\newenvironment<>{cor}
{\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=mydarkpurple, bg=mylightpurple}%
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=mylightpurple}%
\begin{block}{Corollary} #1}
{\end{block}}

\newenvironment<>{prop}
{\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=mydarkpurple, bg=mylightpurple}%
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=mylightpurple}%
\begin{block}{Proposition} #1}
{\end{block}}

\newenvironment<>{claim}
{\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=mydarkpurple, bg=mylightpurple}%
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=mylightpurple}%
\begin{block}{Claim} #1}
{\end{block}}

\newenvironment<>{thm}[2]
{\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=black, bg=mygraydark}%
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=mygraylight}%
\begin{block}{#1} #2}
{\end{block}}

\newenvironment<>{mybox}[2]
{\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=black, bg=mygraydark}%
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=mygraylight}%
\begin{block}{#1} #2}
{\end{block}}

%Question block
\newenvironment<>{question}[2]
{\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=mydarkpink, bg=mylightpink}%
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=mylightpink}%
\begin{block}{Question} #1 #2}
{\end{block}}


\newenvironment<>{obs}[2]
{\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=mydarkblue, bg=mylightblue}%
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=mylightblue}%
\begin{block}{#1} #2}
{\end{block}}

%recap block
\newenvironment<>{recap}
{\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=mydarkblue,bg=mylightblue}%
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=mylightblue}%
\begin{block}{Recap} #1}
{\end{block}}


\newenvironment<>{idea}
{\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=mydarkbrown, bg=mylightyellow}%
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=mylightyellow}%
\begin{block}{Idea} #1}
{\end{block}}

\newenvironment<>{myproof}
{\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=mygraydark, bg=mygraylight}%
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=mygraylight}%
\begin{block}{Proof} #1}
{\end{block}}

\newenvironment<>{myproblem}
{\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=mygraydark, bg=mygraylight}%
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=mygraylight}%
\begin{block}{Problem} #1}
{\end{block}}

%
\renewenvironment{proof}{{\bf Proof: }}{\qed}

%new Commands

% Sets
\newcommand{\A}{{\mathbb{A}}}
\newcommand{\C}{{\mathbb{C}}}
\newcommand{\N}{{\mathbb{N}}}
\newcommand{\Q}{{\mathbb{Q}}}
\newcommand{\R}{{\mathbb{R}}}
\newcommand{\Z}{{\mathbb{Z}}}
\newcommand{\F}{{\mathbb{F}}}

% bases
\newcommand{\mA}{\mathcal{A}}
\newcommand{\mB}{\mathcal{B}}
\newcommand{\mC}{\mathcal{C}}
\newcommand{\mD}{\mathcal{D}}
\newcommand{\mP}{\mathcal{P}}
\newcommand{\mS}{\mathcal{S}}
\newcommand{\mT}{\mathcal{T}}


% vector spaces/subspaces
\newcommand{\vsD}{\mathbb{D}}
\newcommand{\vsL}{\mathbb{L}} % vector space of linear mappings
\newcommand{\vsP}{\mathbb{P}}
\newcommand{\vsS}{\mathbb{S}}
\newcommand{\vsT}{\mathbb{T}}
\newcommand{\vsU}{\mathbb{U}}
\newcommand{\vsV}{\mathbb{V}}
\newcommand{\vsW}{\mathbb{W}}
\newcommand{\W}{\mathbb{W}}

% commonly used notations
\newcommand{\sys}[2]{\left[ #1 \mid #2 \right]}

% functions + special set operators
\newcommand{\real}{\operatorname{Re}}
\newcommand{\imag}{\operatorname{Im}}
\newcommand{\diag}{\operatorname{diag}}
\newcommand{\adj}{\operatorname{adj}}
\newcommand{\rank}{\operatorname{rank }}
\newcommand{\spn}{\operatorname{Span}}
\newcommand{\proj}{\operatorname{proj}}
\newcommand{\prp}{\operatorname{perp}}
\newcommand{\refl}{\operatorname{refl}}
\newcommand{\tr}{\operatorname{tr}}
\newcommand{\nul}{\operatorname{Null}}
\newcommand{\nully}{\operatorname{nullity}}
\newcommand{\range}{\operatorname{Range}}
\newcommand{\col}{\operatorname{Col}}
\newcommand{\row}{\operatorname{Row}}
\newcommand{\cof}{\operatorname{cof}}
\newcommand{\Num}{\operatorname{Num}}
\newcommand{\Id}{\operatorname{Id}}
\newcommand{\inj}{\operatorname{inj}}
\newcommand{\DOT}{\operatorname{DOT}}
\newcommand{\CROSS}{\operatorname{CROSS}}
\newcommand{\ip}[2]{\langle #1, #2\rangle} % inner products

%vectors in R^n
\newcommand{\vzero}{\overrightarrow{0}}
\newcommand{\va}{\overrightarrow{a}}
\newcommand{\vb}{\overrightarrow{b}}
\newcommand{\vc}{\overrightarrow{c}}
\newcommand{\vd}{\overrightarrow{d}}
\newcommand{\ve}{\overrightarrow{e}}
\newcommand{\vf}{\overrightarrow{f}}
\newcommand{\vg}{\overrightarrow{g}}
\newcommand{\vh}{\overrightarrow{h}}
\newcommand{\vJ}{\overrightarrow{J}}
\newcommand{\vm}{\overrightarrow{m}}
\newcommand{\vn}{\overrightarrow{n}}
\newcommand{\vp}{\overrightarrow{p}}
\newcommand{\vq}{\overrightarrow{q}}
\newcommand{\vr}{\overrightarrow{r}}
\newcommand{\vs}{\overrightarrow{s}}
\newcommand{\vt}{\overrightarrow{t}}
\newcommand{\vtt}{\overrightarrow{t}\thinspace ^2}
\newcommand{\vu}{\overrightarrow{u}}
\newcommand{\vv}{{\overrightarrow{v}}}
\newcommand{\vw}{\overrightarrow{w}}
\newcommand{\vx}{\overrightarrow{x}}
\newcommand{\vy}{\overrightarrow{y}}
\newcommand{\vz}{\overrightarrow{z}}

\newcommand{\pfx}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}}
\newcommand{\pfy}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}}
\newcommand{\px}{\frac{\partial}{\partial x}}
\newcommand{\pxn}[2]{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{#1}}}
\newcommand{\py}{\frac{\partial}{\partial y}}
\newcommand{\jacu}{\frac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial(x,y)}}
\newcommand{\jacx}{\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}}
\newcommand{\defbf}[2]{{\bf #1}}

%environments
\def\soln{\vskip10pt\noindent {\bf Solution:} }
%\newcommand{\lec}[2]{\vskip15pt\noindent\underline{\bf Lecture #1 :}\vskip10pt}
%\newcommand{\con}{\noindent\underline{Content:} \hskip5pt}
\newcommand{\prob}{\vskip10pt\noindent\underline{Problem:} \hskip5pt}
\newcommand{\ex}[2]{\vskip10pt\noindent\underline{Example #1:}\hskip7pt}
%\newcommand{\defn}{\vskip10pt\noindent\underline{Definition:}\hskip7pt}
\renewcommand{\note}{\vskip5pt\noindent{\bf Note:}\hskip5pt}
\newcommand{\rema}{\vskip5pt\noindent{\bf Remark:}\vskip5pt\noindent}
\newcommand{\notes}{\vskip5pt\noindent{\bf Notes:}\vskip5pt\noindent}
\newcommand{\proofd}{\vskip5pt\noindent{\bf Proof:}\hskip7pt}
\newcommand{\proofno}{\vskip5pt\noindent{\bf Proof:}\thickspace}
\newcommand{\notation}{\vskip5pt\noindent{\bf Notation:}\vskip5pt\noindent}

%my stuff

\newcommand{\squeeze}[2]{
  \begin{center}\begin{minipage}{#1\textwidth}
   #2 \end{minipage}\end{center}}

\newcommand{\squeezenc}[2]{
  \begin{minipage}{#1\textwidth}
   #2 \end{minipage}}

\newcommand{\cols}[4]{
  \begin{columns}[T]
    \begin{column}{#1\textwidth}  
      #3
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{#2\textwidth}
      #4
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
  }

\newcommand{\ovl}[2]{
  \begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{#1\textheight}
    #2
  \end{overlayarea}
}

\newcommand{\opt}{\ensuremath{\mbox{opt}}}
\newcommand{\blue}[2]{{\usebeamercolor[fg]{blue text} #1}}
\newcommand{\green}[2]{\textcolor{approvedgreen}{#1}}
\newcommand{\red}[2]{{\usebeamercolor[fg]{red text} #1}}
\newcommand{\0}{\mathbb{0}}
\newcommand{\1}{\mathbb{1}}
% \newcommand{\st}{\mbox{s.t.}}

\newlength{\wideitemsep}
\newlength{\origitemsep}
\setlength{\origitemsep}{\itemsep}
\setlength{\wideitemsep}{\itemsep}
\addtolength{\wideitemsep}{1pt}
\let\olditem\item
\renewcommand{\item}{\setlength{\itemsep}{\wideitemsep}\olditem}
```

Comment: Are you sure the templeates modify the `\paperwidth` (width of the slide) or the margins (which modify the width of the text area) ?

Comment: @BambOo  I'm pretty new to this someone gave me a template to use and now images that previously appear side by side appear on top of the other despite there being enough room.

Comment: Well, you should really post an example of what happens and the associated code, otherwise, we won't be able to provide much help.

Comment: @BambOo updated with  template I had iinitally left it out as it was long

Comment: Based on the them you provided, specifically at the end, there are some `\item` length re-definitions that may have a role in this. Regarding you example `frame`, there is a line break between you two `\includegraphics` call so if there is not enough room the second will move to the next line. Try `\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{image1}\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{image2}` or remove the blank line and add a `%` after the first `\includegraphics`.

Comment: @BambOo  I've removed the line break,    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{PreTiling.png}  \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{tiling}

and I'm convinced that's not the issue, as   if I make the images smaller they do appear side by side  so I'm convinced it's a setpagewidth issue   just to be clear at current size, they can fit on a different beamer template so I feel there must be something strange going on with the page width.

Comment: I am sorry, but I am flying blind here. Can you post the code and the output of the problematic frame ? I mean a compilable (reproduceable) example

Comment: @BambOo  I've added the \newif\ifhandout \input{mytalk11}  I can't insert both images idk why anyways I find that this  mytalk11.tex sets a shorter page width than normal because the two images which used to appear side by side no longer do so   Actually two copies of the same image   \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{PreTiling.png}   \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{PreTiling.png}    also appear vertical when there definitely is enough space  If I make the images quite small then they do so I think it's because pagewidth has somehow been reduced.

Comment: Again, please make your example compilable, see [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) to learn how to proceed

Comment: @BambOo  Okay I think it should compile now.

Comment: Frankly I do not know what you want, this is kind of very specific class, so if you do not like the margins as they are, use e.g. `\setbeamersize{text margin left=10mm,text margin right=10mm}` To change them the way you want. Regardless of such settings, writing `\includegraphics{a}%(newline)\includegraphics{b}` will display both images side-by side whatever their widths

Comment: @BambOo thx thats what I was looking for

Comment: @BambOo  yes thank you